# JIRA SOAP: Error message: [Could not load validator class] for progressWorkflowAction

Tags: asp.net, soap, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I am using JIRA's SOAP API to change defect's status by jumping from one status to another and everything was fine until I need to jump on "verified" status where user needs to enter some text into textbox field.

I am using **progressWorkflowAction** method and at attempt to jump to this status I am getting an exception:

```
com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteException: Error occurred when running workflow
action To Verified: 
Errors: {}
Error Messages: [Could not load validator class]
```

Any ideas how can I specify this text which is required for this workflow element?

p.s: Have tried this:

```
JiraClient.progressWorkflowAction(token, "DEF-5", "171", new RemoteFieldValue[] { new RemoteFieldValue { id = "customfield_10175", values = new string[] { "test" } } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to install [JIRA Suite Utilities plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities) ([source](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Could+not+Load+Validator+Class+due+to+JIRA+Suite+Utilities)) according to your Jira version. This is probably the reason for this error.

If it doesn't help, have a look at [Cannot Create Issues due to 'Could not load validator' class Errors:](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Cannot+Create+Issues+due+to+%27Could+not+load+validator%27+class+Errors)

> **Cause**
>
> Some JIRA instances rely on 3rd party workflow validator tools to set
> conditions, validators or post-functions on an issue during it's
> lifecycle at some issue operation or transition within a workflow.
> JIRA will lazily load any 3rd party classes required at the first time
> of use. If the class is not present, the issue creation may fail.
>
> **Diagnosis**
>
> - Browse to the appropriate project administration screen.
> - From there, browse to the workflow in use.
> - Find the transition that's throwing the error.
> - Note the particular validator. The validator will specify a code that suggests which plugin you need. Check the resolution for the
>   known plugins that cause this issue.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Download the applicable Jar from the vendor. A clue of the plugin responsible is often yielded from the stack trace; check
> for the name of the vendor. The set of known plugins to  cause this issue include:
>
> - JIRA Suite Utilities
> - JIRA Misc Utilities
> - Minyaa Suite
>
> *Be sure to use the correct version, and also to remove any previous version of that plugin.*
>
> Once installed, restart JIRA.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the workflow of the DEF project for the issue type of DEF-5. 
Find the transition you want to execute.
Look at the Validators tab
One of the validators will just be showing its class name
This is because the plugin that provided that validator is not present
Reinstall or enable the appropriate plugin.

Another useful test is to try to execute the same transition from the UI instead of the Remote API.